# Threading: I try create a Clock on android but, handler.sendMessage don't have and (super.handleMessagee)

Tags: android, multithreading

[image: The code]

Method **sendMessage** of Handler class can't exist!

Comment: Instead of image you can post your code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use these code to sent message.

```
Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TYPE_ID,stringToSentWith);
message.sendToTarget();
```